# Does the lombok buiilder on constructor should be only one?

Tags: lombok

I thought I could override builders on constructor by args as like the normal java constructors.

But IDE IntelliSense doesn't suggest methods I want.

Does the lombok buiilder on constructor should be only one?

Here's my code:

1. Builders

```
    @Builder(builderMethodName = "builderByDto")
    public SourceInfo(SourceInfoDto sourceInfoDto) {
        this.sourceTitle    = sourceInfoDto.getSourceTitle();
        this.isbn           = sourceInfoDto.getIsbn();
        this.eissn          = sourceInfoDto.getEissn();
        this.issn           = sourceInfoDto.getIssn();
        this.volume         = sourceInfoDto.getVolume();
        this.pages          = sourceInfoDto.getPages();
        this.issue          = sourceInfoDto.getIssue();
        this.publishedYear  = sourceInfoDto.getPublishedYear();
        this.publishedDate  = sourceInfoDto.getPublishedDate();
    }

    @Builder(builderMethodName = "builderByLiteRecord")
    public SourceInfo(LiteRecordDto liteRecordDto) {
        Map<String, String> source = liteRecordDto.getSource();

        this.sourceTitle    = source.get("sourceTitle");
        this.isbn           = source.get("isbn");
        this.eissn          = source.get("eissn");
        this.issn           = source.get("issn");
        this.volume         = source.get("volume");
        this.pages          = source.get("pages");
        this.issue          = source.get("issue");
        this.publishedYear  = source.get("publishedYear");
        this.publishedDate  = source.get("publishedDate");
    }
```

2. Init

```
    @Builder
    public Paper(PaperDto paperDto) {
        ...
        this.sourceInfo     = SourceInfo.builderByDto()
                .sourceInfoDto(paperDto.getSourceInfo()).build();  // Error
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two constructor-based builders, you also need two separate builder classes. You can customize the builder class as follows:

```
@Builder(builderClassName = "BuilderByLiteRecord", builderMethodName = "builderByLiteRecord")
public SourceInfo(LiteRecordDto liteRecordDto) {
...
```

PS: At least from what you showed in your example, the builder pattern seems not really fitting here, at least not for the constructors.
I would put the `@Builder` only on the class, so that you get a builder class with all the fields. Then use two static methods that each take one of your DTO classes as parameter and return a builder filled with the data from the DTO.